# Python Chefboost feature importance No file found like outputs/rules/rules_fi.csv

Tags: python

I am using Chefboost to build Chaid decision tree and want to check the feature importance. For some reason, I got this error:

> cb.feature_importance()
> Feature importance calculation is enabled when parallelised fitting. It seems that fit function didn't called parallelised. No file found like outputs/rules/rules_fi.csv

This is my code:

```py
from chefboost import Chefboost as cb
X_train['Decision']=y_train
config={'algorithm': 'CHAID','enableParallelism': enableParallelism}
cb.fit(X_train,config)
cb.feature_importance()
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: this is to use Chaid decision tree to predict. Anyone knows?

Comment: or is there anyone know how to fit the CHaid in python and share some example code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using the code below.

```
from chefboost import Chefboost as cb
X_train['Decision']=y_train
config={'algorithm': 'CHAID','enableParallelism': True}
cb.fit(X_train,config) 
cb.feature_importance()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run parallel anymore. Feature importance function expects the exact path of rules.py. Be sure to upgrada your chefboost library first.

```
config={'algorithm': 'CHAID'}
model = cb.fit(X_train, config)

#get decision rules
#decision rules = "outputs/rules/rules.py" #static way
decision_rules = model["trees"][0].__dict__["__spec__"].origin #dynamic way
cb.feature_importance(decision_rules)
```